# Dapper insert DateTime value

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I am using dapper CROD operation.

I am trying to enter a new row to a table with DataTime field.

I have created the following class:

```
 //Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActiveStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

Now, the insert statement is as follow:

```
public static string InsertNewMessage
        => @"INSERT INTO Messages 
(Title,[Message],UserID,CreationDate,UpdateDate,ActiveStartDate,
ExpirationDate)
            VALUES (N'@Title',N'@Message',@UserID,CAST('@CreationDate' as 
DATETIME),CAST('@UpdateDate' as DATETIME),
CAST('@ActiveStartDate' as DATETIME)
,CAST('@ExpirationDate' as DATETIME))
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)";



int returnId = _db.Query<int>(QueriesRepository.InsertNewMessage,
    _message).SingleOrDefault();
```

Now what am i doing wrong - i have dig the web for a solution for the following error - with no luck
I know the problem is the formatting of the DateTime object, but i saw that Dapper should support that.

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
```

Comment: It should have worked, Most probably error is with your data base server setting and the format you are passing, Check for Query generated by the dapper using some profiler, Edit your question with query generated, and culture setting of the db user used by the app for updating database.

Comment: Thank you, using the SQL profiler i was able to locate the problem. I will post the resolution so it will be available for others

Comment: There is no need to do the `CAST`, Dapper can handle DateTime

Answer (score 2):

I believe it quite a late response. But anyway I faced the same issue yesterday, so I'll put my solution here. You don't need to CAST datetime directly in sql query. In my case datetime value was out of range, basically, it was 01-01-0001 00:00:00 so that caused the error. Make you sure you pass correct datetime value. Hope this helps!